# Creating 2D-array/ or grid with ocatgon shape in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, grid, polygon

I am trying to create a grid starts for example from

```
import numpy as np
x= np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
y= np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
X,Y= np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

...and inside the grid at the center of it I would like to have a octagon filled shape with edge size of (a), where everywhere in the grid is 0 but the octagon is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way!

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from skimage.morphology import octagon
    oct= octagon(100,100)
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(oct)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

and the result will be :

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjyQW.png)